# Remote Access without Teamviewer or Hamachi - Part 1 of 2

Tags: vpn, arch-linux, remote-access, home-server, raspberry-pi

I want to securely access my Raspberry Pi running Arch Linux from far, far away. (The entire system is running on a 2GB microSD card by the way.) I'm not afraid of the bash shell and I'm not afraid to work hard to get this done.)

Questions:

- Do I need to setup a virtual private network VPN?
- If I do need a VPN, would you recommend openVPN or something else?
- Do I need to learn about network address translation (NAT)?
- Do I need to learn about port forwarding?

Current Tools:

- I have SSH setup on the Pi.
- I have VNC setup on the Pi.

Preferences:

- I don't want to use Hamachi because it limits your connections unless you pay a ton of money.
- I don't want to use TeamViewer because I feel that its very inefficient and bloated.
- Basically, I don't like the idea of sending my information through some company as a way of sacrificing control and freedom for convenience.

P.S. If I would have better luck posting this question on a different forum, which one would you suggest?

Part 2 of this discussion can be found here: [Remote Access without Teamviewer or Hamachi - Part 2 of 2](https://superuser.com/questions/610658/remote-access-without-teamviewer-or-hamachi-part-2-of-2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need a VPN to do that... only to forward on your router the SSH and VNC ports (something like 22 and 5900) to your RPi address. If you have a fixed IP (or a dynamic but with a service like DynDNS), it should work.

You could also set up a VPN if you like more security/privacy, and in that case OpenVPN is great.

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, pataluc, but if my Raspberry Pi is plugged into my computer at home in Texas and I was visiting my parents in New York, how would I remotely access my computer from my parents house? For example what IP address would I connect to, like via putty on my parents' Windows computer?

Comment: @Rhyknowscerious - Just forwared the ports to the device.

Comment: To summarize. pataluc and Ramhound have informed me that this is not an issue of which software to use; It is an issue with understanding port forwarding. Now that I know __what__ to do, I need to know __how to do it__. That discussion can be found here: http://superuser.com/questions/610658/remote-access-without-teamviewer-or-hamachi-part-2-of-2